# Drawing on a panel by clicking a button in WinForms

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio

I'm trying to make a program to draw on the a `Panel` (a square, circle, etc...) by clicking on a button.

I have not done much so far, just tried the code drawing directly to the panel but don't know how to move it to the button. Here is the code I have so far.

If you know a better method to draw than the one I'm using please let me know.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void mainPanel_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        Graphics g;
        g = CreateGraphics();
        Pen pen = new Pen(Color.Black);
        Rectangle r = new Rectangle(10, 10, 100, 100);
        g.DrawRectangle(pen, r);
    }

    private void circleButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    }

    private void drawButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    }
}
```

}

Comment: For starters: This: `Graphics g;
        g = CreateGraphics();`should be: `g = e.Graphics`! And to draw different stuff you need to collect those things in a List<T> and draw them all in the `Paint` event.. See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A3152130+drawaction) for several posts of mine that discuss the ways to do graphics in winforms by creating a drawAction class!
`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using this extremely simplified example class..:

```
class DrawAction
{
    public char type { get; set; }
    public Rectangle rect { get; set; }
    public Color color { get; set; }
    //.....

    public DrawAction(char type_, Rectangle rect_, Color color_)
    { type = type_; rect = rect_; color = color_; }
}
```

Have a class level `List<T>`:

```
List<DrawAction> actions = new List<DrawAction>();
```

you would code a few buttons like this:

```
  private void RectangleButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    actions.Add(new DrawAction('R', new Rectangle(11, 22, 66, 88), Color.DarkGoldenrod));
    mainPanel.Invalidate();  // this triggers the Paint event!
}


private void circleButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    actions.Add(new DrawAction('E', new Rectangle(33, 44, 66, 88), Color.DarkGoldenrod));
    mainPanel.Invalidate();  // this triggers the Paint event!
}
```

And in the `Paint` event:

```
private void mainPanel_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
{
    foreach (DrawAction da in actions)
    {
        if (da.type == 'R') e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(new Pen(da.color), da.rect);
        else if (da.type == 'E') e.Graphics.DrawEllipse(new Pen(da.color), da.rect);
        //..
    }
}
```

Also use a double-buffered `Panel` **subclass**:

```
class DrawPanel : Panel
{ 
    public DrawPanel() 
    { this.DoubleBuffered = true; BackColor = Color.Transparent; }
}
```

The next steps will be to add more types, like lines, curve, text; also colors, pen widths and styles. Also make it dynamic, so that you pick a tool and then click at the Panel..

For freehand drawing you need to collect a `List<Point>`  in the `MouseMove` etc..

Lots of work, lots of fun.

**Updates from comments:**

Note: This is, as I wrote extremely simplified. I have character to draw shapes like Rectangle and Ellipse. With a little more code you can add more characters for a filled rectangle and a filledEllipse. But a) the shapes really ought to be in an Enum and b) more complicated shapes like lines, polygons, text, or shapes with rotation will need more data that just a Rectangle. .

The restriction to rectangle coodinates was a simplification, not so much of the shape but of the data structure. Your other shapes could be reduced to fit in a rectangle (four triangles and two hexagons come to mind); just add charcters and new drawxxx calls.. But evetually adding a List for complex shapes and maybe a string and a font will allow for more complex results..

Comment: Hi, thank you for your help, I started all over and when I try to make the class 'DrawAction' i get an error because it dose not recognise 'Rectangle' or 'Color'... where I should declare them ?

Comment: If you have created from scratch, as you should, in a new file you need to include the necessary `using` clauses; here you are missing `using System.Windows.Forms;` there may be others!

Comment: Yes, I did. I worked on it for about 3 days and It's working, now I'm trying to let the user choose the colour. Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: P.S. I tried to up-vote your answer but I couldn't because I need to have more reputation to do that, sorry.

Comment: Yes, it takes 15 points. However, if you found it useful in solving your problem you can [accept the answer.](http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer)

Comment: Note: This is, as I wrote extremely simplified. I have character to draw shapes like Rectangle and Ellipse. With a little more code you can add more characters for a filled rectangle and a filledEllipse. But a) the shapes really ought to be in an Enum and b) more complicated shapes like lines, polygons, text, or shapes with rotation will need more data that just a Rectangle. .

Comment: The restriction to rectangle coodinates was a simplification, not so much of the shape but of the data structure. Your other shapes __could__ be reduced to fit in a rectangle (four triangles and two hexagons come to mind); just add charcters and new drawxxx calls.. But evetually adding a List<Point> for complex shapes and maybe a string and a font will allow for more complex results..