# c# MainForm graphics from another class erased

Tags: c#, winforms, class, graphics, drawing

I want to draw some lines on a panel which belongs to Form1 in a tab, from another class
I have tried to pass the Form1, the panel in parameters, i can draw what i want, however when the class drawing method is done, if i swap tabs from my UI, the drawings are gone...

Form1 button;

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        panel1 = new Class1().Graph_set_axis(panel1);
    }
```

the class1 method;

```
public Panel Graph_set_axis(Panel _local)
    {

        Pen pen = new Pen(Color.Black, 2);
        Point Origin = new Point(0, 0);
        Point A = new Point();
        Point B = new Point();
        Graphics G = _local.CreateGraphics();
        G.TranslateTransform(0, _local.Height);
        G.ScaleTransform(1.0F, -1.0F);

        A.X = 0;
        A.Y = _local.Height;
        B.X = _local.Width;
        B.Y = 0;
        G.DrawLine(pen, Origin, A);
        G.DrawLine(pen, Origin, B);

        int Y_units;
        int X_units;
        //    int i = 1;

        Y_units = _local.Height / 30;
        for (int i = 0; i * Y_units < _local.Height; i++)
        {
            A.X = 0;
            A.Y = i * Y_units;
            B.X = A.X + 5;
            B.Y = A.Y;
            G.DrawLine(pen, A, B);
        }

        X_units = _local.Width / 30;
        for (int i = 0; i * X_units < _local.Width; i++)
        {
            A.X = i * X_units;
            A.Y = 0;
            B.X = A.X;
            B.Y = A.Y + 5;
            G.DrawLine(pen, A, B);
        }

        return _local;
    }
```

is there a parameter i need to set on the panel1 to keep its drawings ?

Thanks

Comment: _Graphics G = _local.CreateGraphics();_ this is  basically __always wrong__. Never use `control.CreateGraphics`! The result will __not persist__, as you found out..Never try to cache a `Graphics` object! Either draw into a `Bitmap bmp` using a `Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(bmp)` or in the `Paint` event of a control, using the `e.Graphics` parameter..

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why does text drawn on a panel disappear?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/946150/why-does-text-drawn-on-a-panel-disappear)

Comment: If you want to draw __several__ lines etc you need to create one or more __lists__ of those things and draw them _all__ in the paint event! You may want to read throught [this example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35219758/drawing-on-a-panel-by-clicking-a-button-in-winforms/35220601?s=4|0.2084#35220601)