# Drawing shapes using mouse and using List <yourDrawAction>

Tags: c#, winforms, class, drawing, shapes

TaW told me to look at some of his answers and send me this link : [Drawing on a panel by clicking a button in WinForms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35219758/drawing-on-a-panel-by-clicking-a-button-in-winforms/35220601)

I used the code. In DrawAction class I wanted to declare Rectangle, triangle, hexagon and Ellipse. However there was only Rectangle in structs. I couldn't see other shapes.

My question is how can I declare other shapes using this way ?

Comment: I don't think you can ask this question here. I'll add a comment or two to the original post.. Also note that it also contains code to draw Ellipses! The restriction to rectangle coodinates was a simplification, not so much of the shape but of the data structure. Your other shapes __could__ be reduced to fit in a rectangle (four triangles and two hexagons come to mind); just add charcters and new drawxxx calls.. But evetually adding a List<Point> for complex shapes and maybe a string and a font will allow for more complex results..

Comment: Thank you TaW, now I get it. It will be Rectangle in DrawAction class. But later I can draw a Polygon in Panel1Paint right ?

Comment: To draw Polygon you need to add another field to the class: `List<Point> Points`. And you will need some other way to collect the points. But the drawing code will be just one more line: `else if (da.type == 'P') e.Graphics.DrawPolygon(new Pen(da.color), da.Points.ToArray());`

Comment: Can I keep polygons' color ? Because I will try to save the points into txt and load it again to draw different shapes.

Comment: If by 'keep color' you mean can you save it, yes of course. I would recommend to go for serializing, which is wonderfully easy, [see here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50015111/moving-the-mouse-according-to-the-given-coordinates/50018092?s=1|0.0000#50018092) for an example of serializing a list of points. In that case you would have to save the color as a `long c = someColor.ToArgb();`  See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40122284/serialize-media-and-shapes-objects/40124771#40124771) for more on serializing shape classes..

Comment: I used DrawAction class to draw rectangles and ellipses. I draw 2 rectangles. First rectangle didn't dissappear. It's okay. But after that I draw an ellipse. And rectangles turned into  ellipses. I had 3 ellipses. What did I do wrong ?

Comment: How did you set the type character?

Comment: I declared a string named SelectedShape. There are 4 buttons for each shape(Hexagon, Triangle, Rectangle, Ellipse). When one of them clicked, SelectedShape = "(name of shape)" . Then in Panel1Paint,  if (SelectedShape == "Rectangle"){ (drawing code in here) }

Comment: Well that will only work for the newest shape. Do you create new instances of the DRawAction class? Its type property ought to be set; then it should be able to decide what to draw for each shape individually..

Comment: I tried using type property now but still it doesn't work :/

Comment: Hi I solved all my problems. One left. While adding a new DrawAction to the list, the Rectangle only takes 4 parameters. So I can draw Rectangle and Ellipse. But for drawing a Triangle I use 3 parameters. What should I do ?

Comment: I suggest going all the way. (Planning for growth is one of the sectrest of successful coding btw). By this I mean adding  the new property List<Point> Points to the class __and__ extanding the mouse code to allow for adding single points upon mouse clicks. For this you should have (as you probably do) a tool mode. This now should include Polygon and when active each mouseup add a points to the Points list. -

Comment: A cheaper but much less extensible alternative is, as I already wrote, to deduct a triangle from the rectangle. Four directions come naturally; the point could sit on each middle of the rectangle. The drawing code would use the DrawPolygon method. Of course many more triangles can be drawn when setting each point freely. The same goes for octagons.

Comment: I need to use points when drawing polygon. DrawPolygon(brush,Points). But in Rectangle --->  new Rectangle (point1, point2, point3, point4).  There is a type conversion mistake. It can't convert Points to Integers.

Comment: Indeed. That is why I just wrote: _add the new property List<Point> Points to the class_. If you want a cheap triangle you can get three points like this from a Recrtangle r: `e.Graphics.DrawPolygon(Pens.Red, new[] { new Point(r.X,  r.Bottom), new Point(r.Right, r.Bottom), new Point(r.X + r.Width / 2, r.Y) });`

Comment: I will draw a Triangle so point4 will be somewhere between point1 and point2. So it will draw triangle with 4 parameters but How can I convert points to Integers ?

Comment: But it's drawing code you have written. I need the code to add it to DrawActions list.

Comment: I add shapes to the list on MouseUp. After I draw everything in the list in Panel1Paint